# Revert Word 2013 Spell Check to 2007 style

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

In Word 2007 and prior Spell Check was in a separate Pop Up that allowed editing the word inline and easy use off command keys.

Word 2013 decided to go for a panel that doesn't allow editing in line and using accelerators is a little hit and miss. Plus of course useless options like definition I can't trun off :)

Any way of going back to the Original Spelling mode like you can with Search and Replace or as I'm expecting the answer to be no a good alternative?

[image: Word Spell Panel]